# How to align the x-Axis name label to the end of the x-Axis

Tags: echarts

I am struggling with the alignment of the x-axis label.

- What I currently have is the label to the right of the end of the x-axis: see (1)
- I'd like to have this label below the x-axis and aligned to the end of the x-axis: i.e. so that the right side of the label is always at the end of the x-axis: see (2)

[image]

I am using this [example](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=heatmap-cartesian) - and add some code for the axis-name:

```
xAxis: {
    name: 'axisName',
    //nameGap: -100,
    nameTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 18,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        rich: {
            //position: 'right',
            //verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            //textVerticalAlign: 'bottom'
            
        }
    }
```

I am not sure where to start. I've tried multiple align/nameGap/rich options, but couldn't find a solution.

Related:

- [#9276 axis align option ignored](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/pull/9273)

Comment: Use nameGap and in nameTextStyle object the padding property. It's an array of numbers [top,right,bottom,left]. [docs](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#xAxis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that echarts bug [#8444: axis align option ignored](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/8444) has been fixed (since 4.3.0), we can make this work

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tmtron/93qu02dw/15/)

The **horizontal** aligment is easy and works as expected:

- `nameLocation: 'end'`
- `nameTextStyle.align: 'right'`
- set `nameGap=0`: the default is 15 and would move the label too far to the right

These **vertical** alignment settings work as expected

- `verticalAlign: 'top'`
- `padding: [30, 0, 0, 0]`: set top-padding to move the text down

```js
  xAxis: {
    name: '123456789123456789',
    nameLocation: 'end',
    // the default nameGap=15 would move the text to the right
    nameGap: 0,
    nameTextStyle: {
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      /**
       * the top padding will shift the name down so that it does not overlap with the axis-labels
       * t-l-b-r
       */
      padding: [30, 0, 0, 0],
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nameGap with a negative value for the right margin and the nameTextStyle.padding property for the top margin.

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: hours,
    splitArea: {
        show: true
    },
    name: 'x-axis',
    nameGap: -30,
    nameTextStyle: {
        padding: [50,0,0,0]
    }
}
```

Comment: that does not really work, because we would need different gap/padding depending on the length of the axis-name: e.g. try with name: `Temperature [deg. Celcius]`

Comment: Yeah, then it's really bad, that the Alignment doesn't work.